# How to change maven outputdir value during run time?

Tags: xml, maven

My maven pom.xml file looks like below,

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Output directory for the testng xslt report -->
        <outputDir>\target\testng-xslt-resultsreports</outputDir>       
        <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks>
        <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testDetailsFilter>
        <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals>
</configuration>
```

My question is, during every run i would create a folder and need to update that path to the 
"outputDir" ?
Can this be done?

Comment: Can you show your full pom file?

Answer (score 0):

Use a maven property (with a default value) and pass it from command line.

In the pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <customOutput>\target\testng-xslt-resultsreports</customOutput>
</properties>
...
<configuration>
    <outputDir>${customOutput}</outputDir>
....
```

Now you simpley run your maven command with a parameter to override the default value of **customOutput**:
`mvn install -DcustomOutput=\target\newOutPutDir`

I hope this helps

Comment: Hey thanks! But is there any way to change with in the eclipse?

Comment: Apply the configuration as I suggested and in the eclipse maven configuration, you can add the parameter `customOutput=\target\newOutPutDir`

Comment: Hey! Suppose i want to change that path to like customOutput=\target\newOutPutDir(1).
For my next run. and not manually and i need to do it programmatically. So how can i do that?